# selecting random images and it autors from unsplash api using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having issues with getting random images from Unsplash API using angularjs. I have tried using the following code example I found, but it isn't working:

```
$scope.images = function() {
$http({
  method: "GET",
  header: {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
  },
  url: "https://unsplash.it/list",
}).then(function(res) {
    var totalFound = res.data;

    var photos = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < totalFound; i++) {
      var full = res.data[i].authors;
      var regular = res.data[i].filename;
      var thumb = res.data[i].posturl;

      photos.push({
        full: full,
        regular: regular,
        thumb: thumb
      });
    }

    $scope.photos = photos;
    console.log(totalFound);

  },
  function(res) {
    console.log('error', res);
  });
 }

$scope.images();
```

if i try console.log(photos.tumb) i get undefined

Comment: Photos is an array of objects here. Are you getting undefined with `console.log(photos[0].tumb)` as well?

Comment: Note that in your text you wrote `tumb` instead of `thumb` as it's defined in the code for that object.